# Solve the inequality $2ab \leq ea^2 + \frac{b^2}{e}$

Tags: analysis, inequality

Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers and $e>0$.

Then show that $2ab \leq ea^2 + \frac{b^2}{e}$

I'm not sure how to solve this inequality.

Answer (score 2):

Hint

$$\left( a\sqrt e - \frac{b}{\sqrt e}\right)^2 \ge 0$$

Comment: How do you get to there?

Comment: @Arjihad notice that $(a\sqrt{e})^{2}=ea^{2}$ and $(\frac {b}{\sqrt{e}})^2=\frac {b^2}{e}$.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the good "trick" given by OpenBall, you can see this as a bivariate quadratic inequation in $a,b$, that you can turn to univariate as it is homogeneous, by setting $t:=a/b$ and dividing by $b^2$:

$$2ab\le ea^2+\frac{b^2}e\iff b=0\lor2t\le et^2+\frac1e.$$

Then you can discuss the quadratic inequation by finding the roots and factoring.